# How to set up transaction form in FileMaker Pro?

Tags: filemaker

How do you show a list of records like this (in side by side columns): [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O3BE.png)
[image]

instead of rows? [What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWdmE.png)

[image]

Comment: Not really a question about programming. Consider joining one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange your layout like this:

[image]

then show it in [List view](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/17/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fviewing-records.html%23ww1088275).

Comment: Thank you so much!